# wrap text within rect without overflowing it, fiddle canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to write text within a rectangle inside a canvas....

**PROBLEM**

the text overflow the rectangle...I'm thinking at incrementing the rectangle height with the text lineheight once the function `wrapText()` has been excecuted.....

this is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vf8gvq7m/65/ (more advanced) and for you to make an ideaof what I want to do

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// core drawing function
var drawMe = function() { 
    var ImgGlasses = canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 400;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(20,20,250,50);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    text ="hi hello how are you, i want to fill all this rectangle dinamycally. So this text doesnt overflow the rectangle";
    //ctx.fillText(text,30,30)  

    var maxWidth = 220;
    var lineHeight = 25;
    var x = 30;
    var y = 30; 
 
    wrapText(ctx, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight);  
}
  
function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {
    var words = text.split(' ');
    var line = '';

    for (var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
        var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
        var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
        var testWidth = metrics.width;
        if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
            context.fillText(line, x, y);
            line = words[n] + ' ';
            y += lineHeight;
        } else {
            line = testLine;
        }
    }
    context.fillText(line, x, y);
}  

drawMe();
```

```html
<br/>
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
```

Comment: You need to redefine the size of the rect depending on the size text. After that call to draw method with all elements.

Comment: ok in the fiddle I am changing the value of the initial rectangle height with: `rectheight+=lineheight` (or plus the line height) but it doesnt seem to work because the rectangle is below, please check it out and give me a feedback of it

Comment: You need to redraw all elements, canvas just draw once per instruction, It does not have a real-time update

Comment: is not the canvas the one I want to update its height...its the rectangle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vf8gvq7m/86/

Comment: wow its amazing!!. thanks. feel free to post it as an annswer to mark it....I have this question:    whiy do you multiply by 4 `ctx.fillRect(20,20,250,words.length*4);`

Comment: remember to give answered Question :)

Comment: it adds 4 pixels to rect for each line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define how many words do you have, after that draw `rect` based on length of words.

Example

```
const words =  text.split(' ');
const incrementFactor = 4; // it adds 4 pixels to rect for each line
const paragraphCount = words.length // Define the paragraph count
ctx.fillRect(20,20,250,paragraphCount*incrementFactor);
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
drawWords(ctx, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight,rectHeight,words)
```

You need to redraw canvas in each update.
I suggest first define all elements to be drawn and after that draw it. Canvas does not have real-time updates, you need to redraw in each update.

working code https://jsfiddle.net/vf8gvq7m/91/

Comment: ok..I was testing adding font parameters  `var fontSize ="10"; var fontType="Arial";  ctx.font = fontSize + 'pt '+fontType; and the `increment facto `r is not so accurate...it leave a gap at the bottom`...hodw do I connect the font size-type with this factor to make a single variable?

Comment: check it out please https://jsfiddle.net/vf8gvq7m/96/ just fix that to be perfect

Comment: Just create a function that gives you the incrementFactor size depending on font size

Comment: function getIncrementFactor(fontFeatures){... return myFactor} // you could use decimals or something depending on font styles

Comment: In this case, the factor could be 2.5

Comment: with 2.5 sometimes the text overflows

Comment: You need to create a method based on font styles that returns you the ideal size

Comment: how do I return the number of lines of the paragraph...I could start by that

Comment: Updated, define too paragraphCount function

Comment: ya but I'm still not able to get thhis paragraph lines count https://jsfiddle.net/vf8gvq7m/127/

Comment: I posted another question related to that matter...if you could chek it out would be great! https://stackoverflow.com/q/49615891/9503467 thank you