# Improving drawing whatssap conversation on canvas fiddle html5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm drawing a WhatsApp conversation on a canvas

**PROBLEM**

1) I'm able to resize the rectangle that contains the text, but not accurately....this is the step 1

It depends on the number of lines this text has. I'm currently multiplying it by a predefined `factor` but this is a random factor I set by default....this factor has to be calculated according to the paragraph lines number (or maybe other factors like font-size or font-family..)

Once I finish it I'll publish it on GitHub

this is a working fiddle of my advance https://jsfiddle.net/vf8gvq7m/168/

**Example**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


// core drawing function
var drawMe = function() { 
var img = document.getElementById('bg');
  
canvas.width = 364;
canvas.height = 900;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 364, 662, 0, 0, 364,662);
ctx.fillStyle = '#E1FFC7';

var rectHeight=50;
text = $("#first_text").val();
 

      var maxWidth = 230;
      var lineHeight = 15;
      var x = 20;
      var y = 40; 
      var fontSize ="9"; var fontType="Arial";
 ctx.font = fontSize + 'pt '+fontType;
 
  const words =  text.split(' '); 
  const incrementFactor = 4; // it adds 4 pixels to rect for each line
  const paragraphCount = words.length // Define the paragraph count
  
   var newRectHeight = paragraphCount*incrementFactor;
    ctx.fillRect(10,20,250,newRectHeight); 
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  drawWords(ctx, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight,rectHeight,words)
  
  
  
  }
  
  
  
  
  
   function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight, rectHeight) {
        var words = text.split(' ');
    
        return words
      }
  
  
  function drawWords(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight, rectHeight, words) {
     var line = '';
     lineCountList = [];


    for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
          var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
          var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
          var testWidth = metrics.width;
          if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
            context.fillText(line, x, y);
             count= (n+10);
            line = words[n] + ' ' + count + ' ';
            y += lineHeight;
           
            lineCountList.push((n+10));
            
           
          }
          else {
            line = testLine;
            count= (n+10);
             lineCountList.push((n+10));
          }
        } 
        context.fillText(line, x, y);
         rectHeight=rectHeight + lineHeight; 
         var classes = lineCountList.join(' '); 
         paraghraphCount= Math.floor(count/10);
        // alert(paraghraphCount)
         // alert(lineCountList)
  }
  
  
  
      $("#resetInput").on("click",function(){

$("#first_text").val("");
  drawMe();
});
  
$("#first_text").on("change keypress keyup keydown click",function(){


  drawMe();
});

  
  
  drawMe();
```

```css
canvas{
  margin:20px 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</p>
  <input type="text" id="first_text"> <button id="resetInput">reset</button>

<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
<img id="bg" src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/398893/15136779/4e765036-1639-11e6-9201-67e728e86f39.jpg" style="opacity:0;"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest create a function for line count. And update de pixels factor of the incremental factor

```
const incrementFactor = 30;
const maxLineLengthLine = 30; //max length characters count per line
const paragraphCount = lineCount(text.length, maxLineLengthLine);

function lineCount(charactersCount, maxLineLengthLine){
 maxLine = maxLine?maxLine:1;
 charactersCount = charactersCount ? charactersCount:1;
 return Math.ceil(charactersCount/maxLine)
}
```

see 
https://jsfiddle.net/vf8gvq7m/174/

Comment: ok, thank you for your feedback again they have been so helpful...Well in this case when the writing starts in the input, its got a moment when the gap below the text become huge...

Comment: you need to wrap words, and wrap messages. With a limit count

Comment: ok limiting the text `maxlength=150` it gets better results visually speaking...the problem is when I write a single line the rectangle doesnt grow...not so accurate the height while writing

Comment: The word wrap method has issues you need to fix for split first line

Comment: I'm on it, thank you. I found this http://jsfiddle.net/philfreo/MqM76/ could be a solution

Comment: I added this new question related to the width limits, please check it out https://stackoverflow.com/q/49618611/9503467

Answer (score 0):

If the rectangle is a set width can you determine the height based on the number of characters in the text? So imagine you are able to get 100 characters per line and a line is 5px height. Now you have 242 characters you can divide 242/100 to get 2.42, round up to 3, now you need 5px x 3 lines height to fit all the text.

Comment: but all the characters never have the same witdth, for example `i & w have different widths`

Comment: That's a great point, maybe you could take the average characters per line of a large number of lines and then be conservative with your estimate to make sure you never have too little height to display all lines.

Though this method could still have problems if you need to take into account different typefaces.

Comment: ...have any coding idea?

Comment: Just a high level idea at this point. When I have more time I might be able to go through your fiddle and see what I can recommend code-wise.

Comment: ok. thank you for your concern. I'll be waiting then, this project has still for a couple of days